# Using await inside a ContinueWith() block

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have the following code:

```
var result = MessageBoxHelper.MsgBox
    .ShowAsync("Press Yes to proceed", MessageBoxButton.YesNo)
    .ContinueWith((answer) =>
    {
        if (answer.Result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            Task<bool> asyncTask = ExecuteAsyncFunc();
            //asyncTask.Unwrap(); ??
            asyncTask.ContinueWith((a) =>
            {
                // More 
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        }
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

Invoked elsewhere like this:

```
public async Task<bool> ExecuteAsyncFunc()
{
    await CallAnotherAsyncFunction();
}
```

I believe that I need to call Unwrap(), where I have tried to, because I am calling await inside a `ContinueWith()` block.  However, I get the following error when I uncomment it:

> Error CS1929  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Unwrap'
>   and the best extension method overload
>   'TaskExtensions.Unwrap(Task)' requires a receiver of type
>   'Task'

Do I need to use Unwrap in this context, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you mixing `ContinueWith` with `await`?

Comment: The answer to the various questions about using ContinueWith instead of await is that I'm coming from synchronous code (a game).  ContinueWith seems like a neat way to call an asynchronous function from a synchronous one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is to use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`:

```
var result = MessageBoxHelper.MsgBox.ShowAsync("Press Yes to proceed", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
if (answer == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
  var a = await ExecuteAsyncFunc();
  // More 
}
```

The long answer is that [`ContinueWith` has some dangerous default options (including using an ambient `TaskScheduler`)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html), and `await` automatically does everything correctly for you. I go into more detail on my blog.

Comment: The implication of what you say here (and in your post) is that is the Current TaskScheduler is specified explicitly, the above code should be fine.  Is that your understanding, or is there another reason to not use ContinueWith?

Comment: @pm_2: `ContinueWith` forces you to work in CPS (continuation passing style), which is much more awkward than `await`. Why would you want to use `ContinueWith` instead of `await`?

Comment: Because the calling code is a game loop.  I can't halt the execution of the main loop, so this seemed the easiest way to do that

Comment: @pm_2: It sounds like you're using `ContinueWith` to do a fire-and-forget, which is a very dangerous practice (i.e., how would you detect unexpected exceptions?). `await` always results in cleaner code.

Comment: I need a fire-and-forget method.  I read your article regarding using async void with the same warnings.  So what's the best way to deal with an asynchronous method inside a game loop?

Comment: To do what you're doing today, just call an `async Task` method and ignore the task. But if you do that, you should have a `try`/`catch` and do *something* if an error occurs.

Comment: But if I don't await the task, I can't handle the error - is that not the case?

Comment: @pm_2: If you have a `try`/`catch` around all the logic in the method, that *is* handling the error.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to use Unwrap in this context, and if so, what am I doing
>   wrong?

You need to `Unwrap` only when your return type is a `Task<Task>`, and you actually want to do something with the inner task.

For example:

```
Task<Task> exampleTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
{
   await Task.Delay(1000); 
});
```

If I wanted to actually asynchronously wait on the inner `Task`, i'd call `Unwrap` and `await` on that:

```
Task exampleTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => 
{
   await Task.Delay(1000); 
}).Unwrap();
```

If for any reason you'd want to `await` on any task returned from your continuation, or want to monitor the inner task, then you'd call `Unwrap`. There is no need to do that here.

What you're doing is simply invoking an async method inside your `ContinueWith`, but it doesn't seem like you want to `await` the result at all.

I'd recommend using `async-await` wherever possible to reduce the verbosity of `ContinueWith`. Mixing those two together usually yields bad results as thing get rather complicated. Refactoring that code ends up much cleaner with much less cyclomatic complexity:

```
var result = await MessageBoxHelper.MsgBox.ShowAsync("Press Yes to proceed",
                                                      MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    bool answer = await ExecuteFuncAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You say that you have to call unwrap due to your using await inside the `ContinueWith`; I don't actually see you using await though. I assume what you  meant is that you want to await but are not sure how, and thus thought unwrapping is needed. If that is the case, then what you want is to just make your nested Task awaitable. You can do that by making the delegate you provide `async`

```
var result = MessageBoxHelper.MsgBox
    .ShowAsync("Press Yes to proceed", MessageBoxButton.YesNo)
    .ContinueWith(async (answer) =>
    {
        if (answer.Result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            await ExecuteAsyncFunc();
        }
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

public async Task<bool> ExecuteAsyncFunc()
{
    await CallAnotherAsyncFunction();
}
```

This allows you to await within the delegate, within the ContinueWith call and not have to deal with unwrapping.

If you are going to do anything with the Task, such as return it without unwrapping, then this is the right way to go.

```
public Task<BoolOrSomeOtherReturnType> Foo()
{
    return MessageBoxHelper.MsgBox
    .ShowAsync /* Continue with etc here */
}
```

But if you are going to act on the results within the `Foo` method, then there is no need to use ContinueWith, just await it.

```
public async Task<bool> Foo()
{
    var result = await MessageBoxHelper.MsgBox
        .ShowAsync("Press Yes to proceed", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        await ExecuteAsyncFunc();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

That simplifies your code quiet a bit. The other thing to note is that your `ExecuteAsyncFunc()` method does not act on the return value. You simply await and do nothing else.

I noticed that you're not returning true/false, so I assume there is more code there that you just omitted for clarity sake. If that isn't the case, you can save yourself some overhead and just return the Task, allowing someone further up the callstack to await it instead. If your call to `CallAnotherAsyncFunction` returns `Task<bool>` then you can just return that call in the same way as well. You only need to await if you have to prevent the method from going any further so you can react to the result of the awaited method. If you don't have to, just return the Task.

```
public Task<bool> ExecuteAsyncFunc()
{
    return CallAnotherAsyncFunction();
}
```