# Task.ContinueWith not delaying

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

Why do operations 1 and 2  execute at the same time? and not 30 seconds apart?

Running under IIS on ASP.NET

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Operation 1");
     }
    ).ContinueWith(async task =>
    {
        log("sleeping during turn on");
        await Task.Delay(25000);
        log("finished awaiting");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        log("finished sleeping");
    }
    ).ContinueWith(
        task =>
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Operation 2");
        }
    );

t.Wait();
```

Comment: Please clarify what "task 1" is. With the code you posted, both continuations will effectively execute concurrently. So if "task 1" is supposed to be the first continuation, I'd expect the code to do exactly what you describe. But the way you wrote the comments, it looks like "task 1" is the original task started in the `StartNew()` method. In any case, your question is incomplete, since it lacks a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Please fix the question so it makes sense, and so that it includes a suitable MCVE.

Comment: And for the record, I see nothing in your question that justifies the use of the [tag:asp.net] tag. There doesn't seem to be anything about the question that's actually specific to ASP.NET.

Comment: clarified question, i don't understand why the two console write lines do not run 30 seconds apart

Comment: Ah. That's completely different from claiming they _"execute at the same time"_. They don't. They just both complete very quickly. And that's because your first continuation returns (and so has effectively completed) at the first `await`. There are lots of duplicates of this question already. I will find and close, unless you want to just delete the question outright.

Comment: Because you told them to? `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't understand async; `ContinueWith` doesn't understand async. You said "continue the task as soon as it's complete", and `await` is a special return (=> task is complete). I could tell you how to fix it, but unless you're willing to put the effort to learning exactly how tasks and async work, your best choice is simply *stick with await and forget ContinueWith*. `await` handles most of the hard bits for you, and there's very few things `ContinueWith` can do that `await` can't.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121994/using-await-inside-a-continuewith-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `ContinueWith` returns `Task<Task>`, and you need to `.Unwrap` it:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("Operation 1");
})
.ContinueWith(async task => {
    log("sleeping during turn on");
    await Task.Delay(25000);
    log("finished awaiting");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    log("finished sleeping");
})
.Unwrap()
.ContinueWith(task => {
     Console.WriteLine("Operation 2");
});
t.Wait();
```

For deeper understanding you can check all implementations of `ContinueWith`:
which is used in the first `ContinueWith` and which is used in the second.

Also check `async task => { ...`, you need to understand that it returns `Task`.

And final clarification (if it's not a question about understanding `ContinueWith`), it's better to use `await`:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Operation 1");

    log("sleeping during turn on");
    await Task.Delay(25000);
    log("finished awaiting");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    log("finished sleeping");

     Console.WriteLine("Operation 2");
});
t.Wait();
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain to the op what's going on.

Comment: If it was as simple as that, then changing the first `await` to `Thread.Sleep()` instead would still cause the same behaviour - but it doesn't. If you change the `await` to `Thread.Sleep()` then the OP's expected behaviour does occur.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: while `Unwrap()` seems like a heavy-handed solution to me (the OP would be much better off using `Task.Run()` for the original task, and `await`s for the continuations), it really is "as simple as that". The proposed code above would in fact provide the expected behavior, and it's not true that the fact that `Thread.Sleep()` doesn't cause the same behavior disproves any of this.

Comment: @PeterDuniho True; I misread the answer somewhat.

Comment: Thank you all for your help in this one, i did not realise that the async operator creates its own task and so we receive a nested task. I think this is quite subtle and am very thankful for your kind assistance Hopefully this will help someone else also.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, the fix is that simple, but if the reader doesn't understand *why* the fix is that simple, why it's necessary here, or under what situations it will be necessary going forward, then they're not really being helped, as they'll just continue to run into the same problem in the future.

Answer (score -1):

> Why do operations 1 and 2 execute at the same time? and not 30 seconds apart?

The short answer is that [`ContinueWith` does not understand `async`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html). [Neither does `StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), for that matter. You should not be using `ContinueWith` or `StartNew`.

[Instead of `StartNew`, use `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html), and instead of `ContinueWith`, use `await`:

```
Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  Console.WriteLine("Operation 1");

  log("sleeping during turn on");
  await Task.Delay(25000);
  log("finished awaiting");
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  log("finished sleeping");

  Console.WriteLine("Operation 2");
});
t.Wait();
```

> Running under IIS on ASP.NET

Since you're on ASP.NET, [you shouldn't be using `Task.Run`, either](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("Operation 1");

log("sleeping during turn on");
await Task.Delay(25000);
log("finished awaiting");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
log("finished sleeping");

Console.WriteLine("Operation 2");
```

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest using `Task.Run` at all (in this situation) as it's simply not appropriate for this situation.